# When upgrading Win10 Home to Pro using a Win7/8.x product key from another computer, what happens to the Win7/8.x install?

Tags: windows-10

I am interested in using the method in [this article](https://www.zdnet.com/article/going-pro-how-to-upgrade-windows-10-home-without-hassles/) to upgrade a new computer with OEM Windows 10 Home to Windows 10 Pro. It says this can be done if I have an old product key for Windows 7/8.x Pro/Ultimate, which I do (also OEM, on an older computer I still have).

The article suggests the old product key should be "lying around" or "no longer in use" and I'm not sure what that means. If I use the old product key to upgrade the new computer to Windows 10 Pro, what will happen if/when I subsequently use the computer that has the old Windows install?

Would it be any different if I first upgraded the older computer to Windows 10 (using the [currently available upgrade method](https://www.zdnet.com/article/heres-how-you-can-still-get-a-free-windows-10-upgrade/)) -- would that in any way help "free up" the Windows 7/8.x product key, or is it unnecessary?

Comment: You can't "free up" product key from OEM. It isn't transferable

Comment: The article description a method that doesn’t actually work. You missed your chance to perform an upgrade from Home to Professional by several years.

Comment: @Ramhound Please explain, why do you think that? The article is current and says, "This scenario worked during the early Windows 10 upgrade program, and after some testing and multiple reports from independent testers worldwide I can confirm that it still succeeds in mid-2018."

Comment: You have never been able to go from Windows 10 Home to Windows 10 Professional with a Windows 7 Professional key.  You can upgrade to Windows 10 Professional from Windows 7 Professional.  The problem you face isn't due to a key previously being used.  If the Windows 7 key is a retail key, during the free upgrade period, you could have used it to install Windows 10 Professional.  It was never a valid key to upgrade from Windows 10 (OEM) to Windows 10 Professional.  FYI: **Ed Bott is notorious for spreading incorrect information.**  The "vague" wording he claims is vague isn't vague at all.